# overwrite a file only after the while loop finishes in shell script

Tags: shell, file-io, while-loop

In my shell script I am writing the results of a while loop in an output file, so the output file looks like this:

```
    23
    34
    45
    35
```

But when I use > instead of >> I only get the last number as every previous number gets overwritten, whereas I want firstly to sum up all these numbers and only then overwrite the file in order to run the shell script the second time with new numbers. 
I was wondering if there's a way to do this.

Comment: Perform all your needed tasks before writing to file. You are right, `>>` appends, `>` rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, by storing your results in an array x[]

```
x=($(for i in {1..4}; do echo $i; ((j+=i));done;echo $j))
echo ${x[@]}
1 2 3 4 10
```

You can then write whatever you want to a file afterwards using the saved outputs to generate the file's contents.

**Notes:**

Arrays work like this in the simplest case:

```
x=(1 2 3 4)
echo ${x[@]}
1 2 3 4
```

I sum the loop control variable `$i` into a variable `$j`

`x=($(xyz))` creates an array `x[]` with elements set to the results of running the command `xyz`

`{1..4}` just creates a simple list of numbers for a loop with 4 iterations

`echo ${x[@]}` prints the entire contents of the array `x[]`

I stored the result of the addition in the last element of the array.